# Passing page variable into a Drupal region

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming

I want to put my header and footer of my site in a separate region to simplify my page.tpl.php file so I wonder to know how can I pass a page variable such as main_menu into a region like page_top. By doing so does this cause a performance issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a seperate php files for header / footer and do a php include in you're page.tpl.php file

```
    <!-- ////////// Navigation - start ////////// -->
    <?php include "includes/navigation.php"; ?>
    <!-- ////////// Navigation - end ////////// -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By adding this snip of code on page.tpl.php can I use main_menu in header and footer !!